# Не работает простейшая программа сделанная по руководству

Tags: c, локализация, gettext

Я искал руководства по написанию программ на C с использованием gettext и нашёл [эту с федоры](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_do_I18N_through_gettext) и [эту](https://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/programming/a-quick-gettext-tutorial.html). Пробовал делать оба варианта по инструкции (перевод делал и через терминал, и через poedit) , но всё равно программа выводила непереведённый текст.
Текущий код такой

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#define _(STRING) gettext (STRING)
int main()
{
setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
bindtextdomain ("main_6", getenv("PWD"));
textdomain ("main_6");

printf(_("translated"));
return 0;
}
```

А  кусок текущего main_6.po

```
"Language: ru\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: main_6.c:12
#, c-format
msgid "translated"
msgstr "переведённый"
```

Выводит просто translated. Запускал через терминал с флагами LANG=ru; LANG=ru_RU и меняя локаль в программе. Возможно проблема из-за того что работаю на виртуалке Ubuntu.
Вот дерево в каталоге, немного сделал лишнего и ненужного по идее.

```
├── main
├── main_6
├── main_6.c
├── po
│  ├── main_6.pot
│  └── ru
│     ├── LC_MESSAGES
│     │   └── main_6.mo
│     ├── main_6.mo
│     └── main_6.po
└── ru
   ├── LC_MESSAGES
   │ └── main_6.mo
   ├── main_6.mo
   └── main_6.po
```

Comment: Команду msgfmt не забыли?

Comment: @andreymal не забыл. делал и msgfmt, и копировал в LC_MESSAGES.

Comment: УМВР... mo не забыл сгенерировать? куда разложил файлы и из какого каталога запускаешь программу? пустой `msgid`/`msgstr` в заголовке po опустил только для вопроса?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Из подкаталога Downloads. Там лежит прога и каталог po (ну и исполняемый с .o). В каталоге po main_6.pot и ещё каталог ru. В каталоге ru - mo и po одноимённые с pot.

Comment: @user14716, `main_6.mo` должен лежать в `Downloads/ru/LC_MESSAGES/`... ЗЫ: в следующий раз просто добавь вывод `tree` или `ls -R` в вопрос — под ним есть серая кнопочка [edit]...

Comment: кстати, ещё, в LANG должно быть корректное имя существующей в системе локали... список можно посмотреть в `locale -a`. `ru` — скорей всего ошибка, а простое `ru_RU` может быть и KOI8R-локалью... так что тебе скорей всего нужен `ru_RU.utf8`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил как подсказали. Изначально забыл просто. После некоторых действий с main_6.mo и LC_MESSAGES до сих пор выдаёт версию без перевода. Как локаль беру ru_RU.utf8 или ru_RU

Comment: @Archer5101, вроде всё правильно... запускаешь программу точно из своего корневого каталога? для уверенности можешь явно передать полный путь в `bindtextdomain`...

Comment: `alex@ubuntu:~/Downloads/new_lab$ gcc -o main_6 main_6.c
alex@ubuntu:~/Downloads/new_lab$ LANG=ru_RU.utf8 ./main_6
translatedalex@ubuntu:~/Downloads/new_lab$`. Ну и поменял в `bindtextdomain` на `/home/alex/Downloads/new_lab/`. Либо совсем всё плохо, либо вот я где-то неправильные вещи делаю...

Comment: @Archer5101, а локаль точно собрана? в `locale -a` она есть?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, есть.

Comment: @Archer5101, вот рабочий вариант в виде саморазвёртывающегося скрипта: http://dpaste.com/0ZZE8N8 ... если заработает — ищи глупую опечатку... если нет, то у меня идеи кончились...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Ну произошло что-то странное: перед сном программа запускалась с переводом, а сейчас без. В любом случае спасибо.